# when I launch a dialog, the background position has changed

Tags: angular-material, angular8

as you see from the down below, when I clicked the row of the table then dialog pops up then, this pushes the background image up. I am using angular material design. How can I fix this?

**dialog button**

```
<mat-header-row
    *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"
></mat-header-row>
<mat-row
    (click)="rawClicked()"
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
></mat-row>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put following CSS into your global CSS or in dialog components local CSS (you have to enable view encapsulation in case of local)

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock{
      position: static !important;
      width: initial !important;
      overflow-y: inherit !important;
}
```

This solved the issue for me. Hope this helps.